# EMF developed in a varying magnetic field

Tags: electricity, magnetic-fields, potential, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Let's say there's a cylindrical varying magnetic field (varying at a constant rate) and I have a conducting body, let's say a rod placed in a plane perpendicular to magnetic field. I am having a difficulty understanding why does distance from centre of circle cut in magnetic field by plane of rod affect the EMF the rod will develop.

Comment: Could you express your problem analytically? (what function is the magnetic field). Moreover is your rod a conductor?

Comment: Yes, it's a conductor. Let's say, magnetic field is varying by a constant rate db/dt.

Comment: I think a detailed sketch is needed. Even better if you use some math. Your description is solely verbal and not very clear. What do you mean by cylindrical field?